# what is wrong in my C++ code? Least Common ancestor

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, least-common-ancestor

To begin with I'm not new to C or C++. However, I'm currently working with C++ on Mac Yosemite. I'm just trying to write a recursive function to return the common ancestors of two nodes, that are identified by their key (data) variable. The logic is simple, traverse the tree until both the nodes are in the same branch, the node where these nodes diverge is the common ancestor. With this mind, I came up with the following code:

```
Node * commonAncestor(Node *n, int left_elem, int right_elem)
{
    if (n == NULL || n->key()==left_elem || n->key() == right_elem){return NULL;}
    if (left_elem < n->key() && right_elem > n->key()) {return n;}
    if (left_elem > n->key() || right_elem < n->key()) {
        cout<<"\n...Consider changing the order of the elements"<<endl;
    }
    if (left_elem < n->key() && right_elem < n->key()) {
        commonAncestor(n->Left(), left_elem, right_elem);
    }
    if (left_elem > n->key() && right_elem > n->key()) {
        commonAncestor(n->Right(), left_elem, right_elem);
    }
}
```

I should work, I have done similar programs. However, the program doesn't compile. I'm getting **compiler** error `"control may reach end of non-void function"`
This is strange, as I have return statements. Also, to avoid this error I tried adding a return statement at the end, which only returned the root node. I'm confused... Should I do something with the XCode settings? Is my logic wrong?

Comment: Did putting the return statement at the end fix the error?

Comment: Yes, it let me compile but won't return the correct node. It was returning the root...in this case.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you forgot to return the value returned by your recursive calls. And also add a return `NULL` at the end, since compiler doesn't necessarily know that the end of the function is unreachable.

```cpp
Node * commonAncestor(Node *n, int left_elem, int right_elem)
{
    if (n == NULL || n->key()==left_elem || n->key() == right_elem){return NULL;}
    if (left_elem < n->key() && right_elem > n->key()) {return n;}
    if (left_elem > n->key() || right_elem < n->key()) {
        cout<<"\n...Consider changing the order of the elements"<<endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    if (left_elem < n->key() && right_elem < n->key()) {
        return commonAncestor(n->Left(), left_elem, right_elem);
    }
    if (left_elem > n->key() && right_elem > n->key()) {
        return commonAncestor(n->Right(), left_elem, right_elem);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please read my entire post. As I had mentioned in my post, I did try to add return statement - NULL, as well. In this case, the function returned only returned NULL. However, when I added couts to debug, the flow of control seems to be fine...!

Comment: Well, read my entire answer :) Did you try to add return statements in front of commonAncestor calls, as I suggested? Also, for the case when one of the nodes is an ancestor of another, I would suggest to return `n` in the first branch instead of `NULL` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the returns are always inside IF statements so they could be not called... So the solution should be calling return also at the end of the function if it does go inside any IF (with NULL or the value you want).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler won't be happy unless it is certain something will be returned no matter what (even if your if's take care of all possible scenarios. At the end, where you presume your code will never reach, just throw a `return NULL;` and it will be happy.

Also, I may be wrong, but I believe you also want to return the result of recursively calling commonAncestor in your last two ifs.

Comment: I already tried returning NULL, in which case, the function would return only NULL.